# Vuetify - Close menu dialog with out v-dialog (using activator)

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a menu dialog inside a table column to update a corresponding value.

The menu dialog when opened shows a card with a select box and update button.

The menu is activated using `v-on` which works exactly as intended but I have no way of closing the menu.

Since it's inside a table, using a `v-model` and changing the value causes multiple menus/select boxes to be shown to be opened.

```html
<v-menu :close-on-content-click="false" :close-on-click="false">
   <template v-slot:activator="{ on: { click } }">
      <v-chip @click="click" small>{{item[header.value]}}</v-chip>
   </template>
   <v-card>
      <!-- <v-card-title class="subtitle-2 pb-0 pt-1">Update Status</v-card-title> -->
      <v-select items="Status" class="px-4 pb-2" hide-details label="Status"></v-select>
      <v-card-actions>
         <!-- <v-spacer></v-spacer> -->
         <v-btn color="primary" @click="" text>Update</v-btn>
         <v-btn color="warning" text>Cancel</v-btn>
      </v-card-actions>
   </v-card>
</v-menu>
```

How can I close the menu without using a v-model?

Answer (score 1):

It was an easy solution...

I added a v-model to the menu dialog and created an object in data `display: {}`. The v-model on the menu dialog was `v-model="display[item.id]"` using the item id as an index of sorts and then I could just use a method to close it.

```
close(id) {
      this.display[id] = false;
    },
```

Done.